# Lists of natural numbers with bounded sum and value

Tags: combinatorics

Given some positive integers $n,X,S$, is there a nice formula for the number of $0\le x_1\le\cdots\le x_n\le X$ with $x_1+\cdots+x_n\le S$? Disregarding the sum (or setting $S\ge nX$) the formula is just a binomial coefficient.

Failing a formula, what is the best way to calculate such terms? Are asymptotics known?

Comment: As a very vague comment: I believe this is still an open problem. It has stumped numerous great mathematicians, and no formula is known. There are bounds. Number theory has produced most (if not all) of these.

Comment: @rustyracketman: Do you know of any references (or a name attached to the problem)?

Comment: Possibly "bin packing".

Comment: @martycohen: I don't see the applicability of bin-packing here. Usually there you have several bins and objects of fixed sized to pack in one way. Here you have one bin and objects of varying sizes to be packed in all possible ways. Unless there is some less-obvious bijection?